# navbar opens, but does not close

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

My menu can be opened, but when clicking close nothing happpens. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar">

        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/polls/" class="navbar-brand">
        <i class="fa fa-home" data-animation="tada"></i> Poll App
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/">Alle apper</a></li>
            <li><a href="/admin/">Admin</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:
http://hannisdal.com

```
/static/polls/jquery-core-1.12.4/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
/static/polls/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
/static/polls/angle/js/packages.min.js
/static/polls/angle/js/theme.min.js"
```

Comment: We need to see the JavaScript.

Comment: Your code seems to function properly in Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/7y55TD1mrQ  Toggling of the navbar functions as expected.  Can you elaborate more on your issue?

Comment: Interesting, so it seems like the theme i'm using is causing this, after removing the last two javascripts from the angle theme - /angle/* it's working. 
The theme:
http://help.oxygenna.com/html/angle/